# Security for setns system call

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-namespaces, linux-security-module

Are there any relevant LSM hooks in the Linux kernel, not proposed patches, that can be used to secure the use of the `setns` system call? If there isn't, then what can be used to restrict the namespaces that a process can switch into?

Comment: [The man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html) explains in detail exactly what restrictions there are on joining each type of namespace. What specific type of namespace do you want to restrict, and why are the already-available options not suitable?

Comment: @JosephSibleReinstateMonica Something granular and configurable, a little like the way most LSM policies. The purpose is to prevent processes originating in one mount namespace from switching into any ancestor, sibling, or cousin mount namespace.

Comment: Do you want to restrict processes that are running as root? If so, why, and can you elaborate more on your threat model? If not, doesn't the requirement to have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` in both its user namespace and the new mount namespace's user namespace already prevent that?

Comment: @JosephSibleReinstateMonica That is part of it. `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is not granular and grants the ability to switch between all namespaces. The solution must be able to restrict particular processes from switching to particular namespaces.

Comment: Which of these describes your situation? 1. You have a process that does have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` and so can currently switch to any namespace, but you want to restrict it so it can switch to some but not others. 2. You have a process that doesn't have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` and so can't currently switch namespaces at all, but you want to allow it to switch to certain ones.

Comment: @JosephSibleReinstateMonica Number 1.

Comment: @JosephSibleReinstateMonica I have answered your question.